# Magento SOLR integration does not fill the index

Tags: magento-enterprise, solr

- My Magento version - EE 1.12.0.2

  - Solr - 3.4.0 (runs on jetty)

This is what I have done so far.

1. Downloaded  solr 3.4 from [lucene archives](https://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/3.4.0/), decompressed to
   /usr/local/share/solr
2. Overwrote the /usr/local/share/solr/example/solr/conf with my
   Magento installation's /lib/Apache/Solr/conf
3. Set owner of /usr/local/share/solr to jetty
4. Magento settings in Catalog Search - Solr Server Hostname -
   localhost, Port - 8983, Username - Admin, Password - , Solr
   Server Path - Solr (Connection Successful)
5. Reindexed from Magento
6. Went to SOLR admin (http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/) and tried `*:*`
   in query string

But I'm getting 0 results. 
Searching from Magento interface also returns nothing. I think the index is not being filled. But I don't see errors in exception/system logs.

This is what logs in console (jetty) when I try to index Catalog search from Magento backend

```
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:03 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/admin/ping params={} hits=0 status=0 QTime=2 
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:03 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/admin/ping params={} status=0 QTime=2 
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:03 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrDeletionPolicy onInit
INFO: SolrDeletionPolicy.onInit: commits:num=1
    commit{dir=/usr/local/share/solr/example/solr/data/index,segFN=segments_1,version=1437881387384,generation=1,filenames=[segments_1]
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:03 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrDeletionPolicy updateCommits
INFO: newest commit = 1437881387384
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:03 AM org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor finish
INFO: {deleteByQuery=store_id:1} 0 3
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:03 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=json} status=0 QTime=3 
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:05 AM org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor finish
INFO: {deleteByQuery=store_id:3} 0 1
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:05 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=json} status=0 QTime=1 
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor finish
INFO: {deleteByQuery=store_id:4} 0 0
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=json} status=0 QTime=0 
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 commit
INFO: start commit(optimize=true,waitFlush=true,waitSearcher=true,expungeDeletes=false)
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher <init>
INFO: Opening Searcher@5a4cbe6a main
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 commit
INFO: end_commit_flush
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher warm
INFO: autowarming Searcher@5a4cbe6a main from Searcher@45bbe38d main
    fieldValueCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher warm
INFO: autowarming result for Searcher@5a4cbe6a main
    fieldValueCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher warm
INFO: autowarming Searcher@5a4cbe6a main from Searcher@45bbe38d main
    filterCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher warm
INFO: autowarming result for Searcher@5a4cbe6a main
    filterCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher warm
INFO: autowarming Searcher@5a4cbe6a main from Searcher@45bbe38d main
    queryResultCache{lookups=1,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=1,evictions=0,size=1,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=8,cumulative_hits=4,cumulative_hitratio=0.50,cumulative_inserts=4,cumulative_evictions=0}
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher warm
INFO: autowarming result for Searcher@5a4cbe6a main
    queryResultCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=8,cumulative_hits=4,cumulative_hitratio=0.50,cumulative_inserts=4,cumulative_evictions=0}
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher warm
INFO: autowarming Searcher@5a4cbe6a main from Searcher@45bbe38d main
    documentCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher warm
INFO: autowarming result for Searcher@5a4cbe6a main
    documentCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.core.QuerySenderListener newSearcher
INFO: QuerySenderListener sending requests to Searcher@5a4cbe6a main
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.core.QuerySenderListener newSearcher
INFO: QuerySenderListener done.
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent$SpellCheckerListener newSearcher
INFO: Index is not optimized therefore skipping building spell check index for: magento_spell_def
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent$SpellCheckerListener newSearcher
INFO: Index is not optimized therefore skipping building spell check index for: magento_spell_en
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent$SpellCheckerListener newSearcher
INFO: Index is not optimized therefore skipping building spell check index for: magento_spell_fr
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent$SpellCheckerListener newSearcher
INFO: Index is not optimized therefore skipping building spell check index for: magento_spell_de
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent$SpellCheckerListener newSearcher
INFO: Index is not optimized therefore skipping building spell check index for: magento_spell_da
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent$SpellCheckerListener newSearcher
INFO: Index is not optimized therefore skipping building spell check index for: magento_spell_nl
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent$SpellCheckerListener newSearcher
INFO: Index is not optimized therefore skipping building spell check index for: magento_spell_fi
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent$SpellCheckerListener newSearcher
INFO: Index is not optimized therefore skipping building spell check index for: magento_spell_it
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent$SpellCheckerListener newSearcher
INFO: Index is not optimized therefore skipping building spell check index for: magento_spell_nb
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent$SpellCheckerListener newSearcher
INFO: Index is not optimized therefore skipping building spell check index for: magento_spell_pt
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent$SpellCheckerListener newSearcher
INFO: Index is not optimized therefore skipping building spell check index for: magento_spell_ro
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent$SpellCheckerListener newSearcher
INFO: Index is not optimized therefore skipping building spell check index for: magento_spell_ru
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent$SpellCheckerListener newSearcher
INFO: Index is not optimized therefore skipping building spell check index for: magento_spell_es
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent$SpellCheckerListener newSearcher
INFO: Index is not optimized therefore skipping building spell check index for: magento_spell_sv
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent$SpellCheckerListener newSearcher
INFO: Index is not optimized therefore skipping building spell check index for: magento_spell_tr
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent$SpellCheckerListener newSearcher
INFO: Index is not optimized therefore skipping building spell check index for: magento_spell_cs
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent$SpellCheckerListener newSearcher
INFO: Index is not optimized therefore skipping building spell check index for: magento_spell_el
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent$SpellCheckerListener newSearcher
INFO: Index is not optimized therefore skipping building spell check index for: magento_spell_th
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent$SpellCheckerListener newSearcher
INFO: Index is not optimized therefore skipping building spell check index for: magento_spell_zh
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent$SpellCheckerListener newSearcher
INFO: Index is not optimized therefore skipping building spell check index for: magento_spell_ja
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent$SpellCheckerListener newSearcher
INFO: Index is not optimized therefore skipping building spell check index for: magento_spell_ko
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore registerSearcher
INFO: [] Registered new searcher Searcher@5a4cbe6a main
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.search.SolrIndexSearcher close
INFO: Closing Searcher@45bbe38d main
    fieldValueCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
    filterCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
    queryResultCache{lookups=1,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=1,evictions=0,size=1,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=8,cumulative_hits=4,cumulative_hitratio=0.50,cumulative_inserts=4,cumulative_evictions=0}
    documentCache{lookups=0,hits=0,hitratio=0.00,inserts=0,evictions=0,size=0,warmupTime=0,cumulative_lookups=0,cumulative_hits=0,cumulative_hitratio=0.00,cumulative_inserts=0,cumulative_evictions=0}
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor finish
INFO: {optimize=} 0 10
Jul 26, 2015 11:45:08 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=json} status=0 QTime=10
```

When trying to search from the Magento front end getting below log in console

```
Jul 26, 2015 11:30:01 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/admin/ping params={} status=0 QTime=2
```

What I'm missing? Where do I need to check?

Please advice

Comment: Refreshing the index is broken somewhere in EE 1.14.x, contact Magento for support, they have the one or other patch. In our case they sended us a patch which solved the problem. I assume similar issues do exist iin 1.12.x, especially as the indexer has been overhauled in 1.13..